# Observability section not visible in ELK Open Distro 1.13.3

Tags: kibana, elk, elasticsearch-opendistro, elastic-beats

I am using Open Distro 1.13.3 , Kibana v 7.10.2 but I am unable to see the observability section in Kibana. I am trying to implement HeartBeat and use uptime to monitor URL's but unable to see observability section. Any idea what could be the reason for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"observability" is a licensed Elastic.co Kibana feature, not available in OpenDistro (and, by the same token, won't be available neither in OpenSearch)

Comment: The term licensed means Elastic License 2.0 ? which means I can avoid using OpenDistro but still can download from below and use Kibana in my company (on-premise) for free? Is this understanding correct. 
https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana

Comment: yes, correct. Here is the official summary of the three limitations imposed by the elastic license https://www.elastic.co/pricing/faq/licensing#what-are-the-key-changes-being-made-to-the-elastic-license